# Outlook 2003 form Macro

Tags: vba, outlook-2003

I have an existing form in outlook that I need to create a macro for.  It is a formed used to submit data to our corporate office.  Every time, I have to fill in my employee number, address, First and Last, etc... can someone help me create a macro to fill in these fields so I do not have to copy and paste or type my information every time?  Thanks!

Comment: If it's a form can't you edit the design and put in default values?

Answer (score 0):

```
 This HTML email creater.  Insert this into the "Visual Basic Editor in Tools>Macro then run the 
 macro "emailpictures".  It will ask for validation.

Sub emailpicture()
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set objOutlookRecip = objOutlookMsg.Recipients.Add("companyemail@email.com")
objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo
objOutlookMsg.Subject = "Picture"
' add "C:\picture.png as attachment to Outlook message
Set colAttach = objOutlookMsg.Attachments
Set l_Attach = colAttach.Add("C:\path\image.jpg")
' Dereference the  attachment objects before changing their properties via CDO
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set l_Attach = Nothing
'Set body format to HTML
objOutlookMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = "<HTML><head></head><BODY><center><table><tr><td><center><h1>Title </h1></center></td></tr><tr><td><center><h1>Body</h1></center><br /></td></tr><img src=""image.jpg"" alt=image><br /><br /></td></tr><tr><td><center><h3>Hope you will have a worderous day!</h3></center><br /><br /></td></tr><tr><td><center><h3>From</h3></center><br /><br /></td></tr></table></center></BODY></HTML>"
objOutlookMsg.Send
Set objOutlookRecip = Nothing
Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Sub emailfromexcel()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = "person@email.com"
        .BCC = thebcc
        .Subject = "This subject"
        .Body = "This body"
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
   Sub emailfromexcel()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
    .To = "person@email.com"
    .BCC = thebcc
    .Subject = "This subject"
    .Body = "This body"
    .Display
    .Send
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
  End Sub
```